# How to schedule page updates rather than on refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, wordle-game, node-schedule

I am new to Javascript so bare with me. I am working on a Wordle Clone and everytime I refresh the page, the game selects a new word from my array of words. I am wondering if there is a way to make it only do this once per day (at midnight perhaps). This way, I have a daily wordle and, if I refresh, it won't change the word.

Here is my function that sets up the board. I tried setInterval(initBoard(),3600000*24) but it did not work.

```
function initBoard() {
    let board = document.getElementById("game-board");

    for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_GUESSES; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement("div")
        row.className = "letter-row"
        
        for (let j = 0; j < rightGuessString.length; j++) {
            let box = document.createElement("div")
            box.className = "letter-box"
            row.appendChild(box)
        }

        board.appendChild(row)
    }
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` expects a function as the first argument. `initBoard()` isn’t a function. Also, when you close the page, close the browser, shut down the computer, etc., JavaScript will not continue running in the background. You need to check the current date, not rely on an interval that waits for a full day.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! I actually ended up fixing this by using a node module and node-schedule to export one word from my word list. Works great!